# Java create Multidimensional Array from Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having an Array `Object[]` with Elements like:

```
Foo A
Foo B
Foo C
notFoo A
notFoo B
notFoo C
```

I want to create an multidimensional array from this like:

```
Object[0][] = {Foo A, Foo B, Foo C}
Object[1][] = {notFoo A, notFoo B, notFoo C}
```

So if an Element in this Array has in it's first token (eg. Foo) a Name which didn't appear before it's stored in another indece.

So the first token indicates the "Element suite", which leads to another index in the array.

Any ideas how to do it?

**EDIT:** The elements are of type String.

Comment: You could map them using a <T> Map<Class<T>, List<T>> Then you can get the list of the type that you put in, if it doesnt exist, you create one, and you add the value to the list. (Note that the names "A", "B" and "C" are non existant and are only variable names.)

Comment: i agree using maps such as Map<someIdentifier, List<list of identifier type>> and then just load and add to the list when a new entry apears

Comment: @Hendrik remember everyone likes to find questions with an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Map<Object.class, List<Object>>
```

or

```
Map<identifier, List<entries>>
```

then when adding to the map, just check if a Object.class exsist in the map, if it does get the list and insert the object, else insert a new one entry in the map and add the Object to the list. note that this solution supports any key and any value type on the list as long as it is not primitives (ie use wrappers for primitives)

**extra**

using arrays implies that you know the length of the array from the start, it's better to use data structures like List/Map for problems where there is no defined length of the Array/List

**Util Class specified as requeted in comment**

This class contains a private map, a way to add values to the map, as well as a way to get the map, or a 2d array version of the map.

```
public class UtilClass {

    private Map<Object, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void addMapEntry(Object key, Object data){
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(map.containsKey(key)) {
            list = map.get(key);
        }
        list.add(data);
        map.put(key, list);
    }

    public Object[][] getMapAs2dArray(){
        Object[][] array = new Object[map.keySet().size()][];
        int index = 0;
        for(Object key : map.keySet()){
            array[index] = map.get(key).toArray();
            index++;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public Map<Object, List<Object>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

*Main method for testing code above*

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    UtilClass test = new UtilClass();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        test.addMapEntry("foo", "foo"+i);
        test.addMapEntry("bar", "bar"+i);
    }

    for(Object key : test.getMap().keySet()){
        System.out.println("Printing map");
        System.out.println(key + " = " + test.getMap().get(key).toString());
    }

    Object[][] objects = test.getMapAs2dArray();

    System.out.println("printing 2d Array");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(objects));

    System.out.print("Done");
}
```

Output for the main test method is as follows

> Printing map
>
> bar = [bar0, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5, bar6, bar7, bar8, bar9]
>
> Printing map
>
> foo = [foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8, foo9]
>
> printing 2d Array
>
> [[bar0, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5, bar6, bar7, bar8, bar9], [foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8, foo9]]
>
> Done

The UtilClass can also be defined static as

```
public class UtilClass {

    public static void addMapEntry(Object key, Map<Object, List<Object>> map, Object data){
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(map.containsKey(key)) {
            list = map.get(key);
        }
        list.add(data);
        map.put(key, list);
    }

    public static  Object[][] getMapAs2dArray(Map<Object, List<Object>> map){
        Object[][] array = new Object[map.keySet().size()][];
        int index = 0;
        for(Object key : map.keySet()){
            array[index] = map.get(key).toArray();
            index++;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

this makes it possible to acces the functionality without instantiating the class, and may be better if you wish to not make a wrapper for the map containning the data

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to an Array afterwards?

Comment: @Hendrik well yes if an array is abosolutely needed, you can acces the size of the map and the containing list to make Arrays or 2d arrays from that 

Map.keySet() returns a set of the keys in the map
List.size() returns a list's size

then just simply make arrays from the sizes and input the values,            Any specific reason it has to be an array though ?

Comment: @Hendrik i have now made a class that should be able usefull to you as a util class, adding it in the answer

Comment: @Hendrik finshed formatting and optimisng the class, hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: @Hendrik realised that a static class aproach might be better for this case, and thus i added this in teh answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may be an extreme overkill, but will still be fun to have as an example:

```
public static <T> Map<Class<?>, List<T>> splitValues(T[] objects)
{
    Map<Class<?>, List<T>> values = new HashMap<>();

    for (T object : objects)
    {
        List<T> list = values.computeIfAbsent(object.getClass(), k -> new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(object);
    }

    return values;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object[] objects = {
        new Foo(),
        new Foo(),
        new Foo(),
        new Foo(),
        new Integer(6),
        new Integer(4),
        new String("bla1"),
        new String("bla2"),
    };
    Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> map = splitValues(objects);

    System.out.println(map.get(Foo.class).toString());
    System.out.println(map.get(Integer.class).toString());
    System.out.println(map.get(String.class).toString());

    // [org.stackoverflow.Foo@7699a589, org.stackoverflow.Foo@58372a00, org.stackoverflow.Foo@4dd8dc3, org.stackoverflow.Foo@6d03e736]
    // [6, 4]
    // [bla1, bla2]
}
```

However, now I wonder why Class or Class doesnt work.